# Task.Run() & Task.Delay() terminated after sometime

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-services, task, scheduled-tasks

I have created windows service in c# and in that service, I have created 4 threads and running them the background every after 10 sec.

Below is the code:

```
var ThreadSize = 4;    
for (int i = 0; i < ThreadSize; i++)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (1 == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                //Logic
                await Task.Delay(10000, cancelSource.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log the exception
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The for loop will be executed only once and will create 4 threads. I am using Task.Delay to wait the thread for 10 sec and then again executing my logic. It will go and execute my logic every 10 sec.

The code is working fine, but after some time, my all threads getting terminated (Not working). I mean, the code in the logic is not working after couples of hours. 
There is no exception at all. 
Can any one suggested what went wrong. 
Thanks you in advance.

Edited Code:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Process.StartProcess(cancelSource);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    cancelSource.Cancel();
}


public static void StartProcess(CancellationTokenSource cancelSource)
{
    var ThreadSize = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadSize; i++)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (1 == 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Logic
                    await Task.Delay(10000, cancelSource.Token);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Log the exception
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Show more context, esp. how this connects to the Service.Startup() method.

Comment: Posted the code in edited section.

Comment: I would also check the event logs to see why service stops (if ALL threads are terminated the service would stop)

Comment: You shouldn't use Tasks for long running operation (or at least you shoul mark it with right flag)

Comment: windows service needs to return control after 30 seconds, so you should move the starting logic to the background thread/task. Currently in your case since the `StartProcess` will keep on running indefinitely, it will be stopped after 30 seconds

Comment: @peeyushsingh - where do you get that from? The thread that creates the 4 tasks loops and then returns. It shouldn't take even 5 seconds, let alone "run indefinitely"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my bad, saw only the 1=1 part of while loop!

Comment: Logic will internally call the other code. This internal code will completed immediately or may take days to complete.

Comment: Logically, the answer is that something *is* throwing an exception. Which raises the question of why you're not aware of the exceptions. It may be worth adding explicit `ContinueWith` lambdas configured to run on failure and make sure they're writing the details down somewhere you can find.

Comment: OK, now we have `//Log the exception`. What does the Log tell you?

Comment: Log has empty. No exception is logged.

Comment: *No exception is logged.* even when you stop service? then there is something wrong with your logging code

Comment: Yes, this probably means that your logging code is throwing another exception within the `catch` block. As there is no try-catch around your logging code, the task will terminate.

Comment: Make sure you write "Starting Service..." to the log at the earliest point. To verify your logging. And maybe use the EventLog , no need for configuration / write access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is in

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

This effectively means that you don't catch any errors. You might as well remove the try/catch for the same effect, or lack of effect.

The main structure of your Service looks OK, this won't stop by itself. The choice of Task vs Thread is not too important.

Your error happens inside `//Logic` and is not handled.

You will need some form of logging to find out.

Comment: By bad, Actually I am not through-in any exception. I am login into file.

Comment: I still not understand what is the exact issue, but I put my logic code in separate private function and then in that private method, I put try and catch block. Then it is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

If any exception occurs within the `Task.Run`, it will be saved and thrown when the task is awaited. You're not awaiting the task, so any exception that has occurred won't be visible.

You should await the `Task.Run` by either using the `await` keyword or call `.Wait()` on it.

As you're spawning multiple tasks, you could add all of them to a list and then call `await Task.WhenAny(tasks)` which will return when any of the tasks finishes, so you can act accordingly.

[Read this article for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Neither is possible/applicable in this (service) scenario.

Comment: I don't want to wait for 4 task to complete (Any way this will not completed because of while loop). Lets them run in the background.

Comment: If you're in a service, you should create a single manager thread and work from there. You can spawn multiple tasks from that thread and wait for any of them to finish (using `Task.WhenAny()`). They CAN still finish, even if there is an infinite loop in them, because they CAN throw an exception, which will cause the task to stop. Just make sure your manager thread never throws any exception so it can restart the tasks when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I am confused about it. Any example will be relay appreciated.